# why SynchronizedList get method need wrap with synchronized in java

Tags: java

this is get method of SynchronizedList.

```java
public E get(int index) {
     synchronized (mutex) {return list.get(index);}
}
```

Can write it directly like this?:

```java
public E get(int index) {
     return list.get(index);
}
```

Comment: This is how it becomes a "synchronized" list -> because of that statement `synchronized (mutex) {return list.get(index);}`

Comment: Before you ask questions like this about the innards of then Java SE class library, you need to do a lot more reading about how Java concurrency actually works.  Don't imagine it is simple ... or that you can get a proper understanding by asking (naive) questions.  This stuff requires **serious study**.

Comment: And the answer to your question is: No you can't write it that say.  It would be incorrect.   See below for some of the reasons. (Put it this way ... if they *could* have written `get` without the `synchronized`, don't you think they *would* have?)

Answer (score 1):

Then it wouldn't be a synchronised list.

Let's imagine that the list being wrapped is a `LinkedList`.

One thread might have called `get` and be traversing the list, while another thread is removing a node from the list.

Unless both methods lock, the get operation may throw an exception.

Comment: Another reason is that unless you use `synchronized`, you risk one thread seeing stale values ... leading to all sorts of chaos.